# Find the volume - using substitution

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of $\omega=\{(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2 , x^2+y^2\leq ax\}$

$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2 \implies x^2+y^2\leq a^2-z^2$.

Therefore , $a^2-z^2 \leq ax \implies a^2-ax\leq z^2$.

Using substitution $x=a\sin\theta \cos\phi, y=a\sin\theta \sin\phi, z=a\cos\theta,  a>0,0\leq \theta\leq \pi ,0\leq \phi\leq 2\pi$.

$a^2-ax\leq z^2 \implies a^2-a(a\sin\theta \cos\phi)\leq a^2\cos^2\theta \implies 1-\sin\theta\cos\phi\leq \cos^2\theta$.

I don't know how to solve this problem and find the limits of the integral , any help please.

Comment: You tried to substitute one into the other, that never works for surfaces. It gives you their curve of intersection (which you need later) but doesn't help you determine a coordinate system to use. Try drawing what your region looks like.

Comment: To add to Ninad's comment, it is actually the intersection of two regular solids. It might help to consider what happens at any fixed value of $z \in [-a,a]$.

Comment: @user170231 you're close but not correct. The equation you wrote down was wrong, but picture you linked is actually correct.

Comment: Right! Thanks for pointing that out. Redo: Complete the square in $x^2+y^2=ax$ to reveal a cylinder. You can see a rough picture of $\omega$ [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder-SphereIntersection.html)